# Spring Boot: EL is not functioning in JSP

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jsp

I am beginner to Spring Boot, practising creating a Submission Form on one JSP page and returning the entered details to another JSP page. but the ${ expression }  is not working properly. Instead of giving passed values from controller it is showing the expression as it is.

My Code:

**CustomersEntry.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Portal</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="saveDetails">
    Enter Customer ID: <input type="text" name="cid"><br>
    Enter Customer Name: <input type="text" name="cname"><br>
    Enter Customer E-mail: <input type="text" name="cemail"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**savedDetails.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Following customer details have been saved:</h2><br>
<h4>Customer ID: {cid}</h4>
<h4>Customer Name: {cname}</h4>
<h4>Customer E-mail: {cemail}</h4>

<form action="/">
<input type="submit" value="Add more Customers"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CustomerFormController**

```
package com.ashish.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class CustomerFormController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getForm() {
        return "CustomersEntry";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveDetails")
    public String saveDetails(@RequestParam("cid") String cid,
            @RequestParam("cname") String cname,
            @RequestParam("cemail") String cemail, ModelMap m) {
        m.addAttribute("cid", cid).addAttribute("cname", cname).addAttribute("cemail", cemail);
        
        return "savedDetails";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FormSubmission</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FormSubmission</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.37</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am using STS 4, Java 14.
I have searched a lot over google but nothing helps.
I've tried including following dependencies one by one as well, as per solution given by other people but no help.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.37</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope> <!-- with or without this and with runtime as well. -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl for jsp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I would advice against using JSP with an embedded container as there are limitions. One of them is that it requires a WAR and won't work in a JAR with tomcat.

Comment: @M.Deinum it works as from where I am taking reference, it's working fine at their end.

Comment: I nowhere said it wouldn't work, I only noticed that using JSP with embedded containers (at least Tomcat) has limitations. Those are also documented in the Spring Boot reference guide.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree with you that it has limitations, but you said--won't work in a JAR with tomcat. But it works.

Comment: It didn't in older tomcat versions due to how JSP a was loaded, might be that it does in newer but historically it doesn't. Nonetheless, there are still limitations and it is highly advised to use another templating engine.

Comment: Yes I'll definitely shift to others, as of now just  just checking the JSP-Spring Boot working together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer

I have added this to the JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

to the pom.xml file.

updated savedDetails.jsp --

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Customer Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Following customer details have been saved:</h2><br>
<h4>Customer ID: <c:out value="${cid}"/></h4>
<h4>Customer Name:<c:out value="${cname}"/></h4>
<h4>Customer E-mail: <c:out value="${cemail}"/></h4>



<form action="/">
<input type="submit" value="Add more Customers"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included jstl library in your JSP page
put this line in your JSP page/pages and it should work.

You may want to change prefix attribute in the below code(you can choose anything which works for you)

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: by doing so, i got Internal Server Error, status=500, org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application.